# Why are yellow lines appearing on prints from my Epson SureColor P600?

Tags: printing, ink-jet, epson

Recently for no reason, there are yellow lines across my print from my Epson SureColor P600. I cleaned the heads and the problem is still there.  I use Epson ink cartridges, not bootlegs.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Not really a photography question.  I'd recommend you contact Epson support.

Comment: @StephenG - I disagree pretty strongly.  Printing photos is certainly part of photography and understanding the cause of issues related to a particular printing technique is very on topic.  The exact way to fix it on a particular printer might not be a great fit, but understanding what kind of malfunction would cause an inkjet printer to do this seems like a pretty good fit.

Comment: @joy - please attach an example

Answer (score 3):

Source: I am an ex-Epson service tech.

First, this is mostly an educated guess as you havent supplied an example.

The presence of Yellow lines means that there is a LACK of one of the other 7 inks in that area, for example if you are expecting a green area (Grass/trees) and you get yellow, then Cyan/Light Cyan is missing. You can tell which are blocked by printing a test-sheet.

There are various reasons for this, but basically you have blocked nozzles, and the printer needs a proper service as you probably can't clear the problem yourself without wasting a large amount of expensive ink.

If it is in warranty, take the printer to an authorised service centre - they have service inks for just this purpose.

If its out of warranty... time to break out the syringes and cheap inks!